# How do I use static analysis to detect potential stack overflow in FreeRTOS?

Tags: gcc, cmake, stm32, stack-overflow, freertos

I write software for embedded targets (STM32) with GCC and CMake and I want to prevent FreeRTOS stack overflows entirely.

With FreeRTOS you have to supply a stack size for each task you create (third parameter of [xTaskCreate()](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) or [xTaskCreateStatic](https://www.freertos.org/xTaskCreateStatic.html)).
Sometimes the required stack size of the task increases as you add more features to your software. If you fail to manually adjust the stack size the result can be a stack overflow. Detecting stack overflow at runtime doesn't always work (FreeRTOS provides [two different methods](https://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html) for detecting a stack overflow : ). And detecting a stack overflow doesn't prevent it.

To solve this problem I want to either detect a potential stack overflow using static analysis (and generate a compile error) or to recompute the stack size and feed it back into the build process (preferably without building twice).

I compile with `-fstack-usage`, which shows the maximum stack depth for all functions (including task functions) in the .su files of each c/cpp file. I can parse this, with a python script for instance, but this is only known after linking is completed. I can enforce some naming convention to detect tasks by their function name. So the challenge is to what to do with this value once it is extracted.

If I want to feed this value back into a constant I would need to compile or at least link again. Is there an automated way to have a compile time constant added after the linking stage (replacing some placeholder value)?

If I just want to check if the value fed into xTaskCreate I would need a way to parse these function calls. But I don't know how to do this reliably with GCC and CMake.

For now I'm ignoring the extra stack size required for handling interrupts. I can make some conservative assumptions about that for now.

What would be a way to add this feature to my CMake build script?

Comment: "Is there an automated way to have a compile time constant added after the linking stage?" - I don't think that some **automated** way exists. For avoid the second compilation you could e.g. modify in the resulted binary the value of variable, which you use as parameter of `xTaskCreate`. But that modification you need to implement by yourself: `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target`, use some utility for direct modification of the binary, etc.

Comment: Don't forget that GCC's stack usage measurements don't generally work if you use any function pointers.  FreeRTOS makes heavy use of putting function pointers in structs that get passed through a queue, it won't know the stack usage of the task that reads them out and calls them.